# Crash on MobileAds.initialize(this) Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR)

Tags: android, kotlin, segmentation-fault, admob, google-mobile-ads

As of today I've started getting this error:

*A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0 in tid 31968*

on some devices when MobileAds.initialize(this) is called. If I uninstall the program and reinstall, it works as expected the first time the app is opened, but if I close and open the app again I start getting the crash again. Removing MobileAds.initialize(this) also fixes the problem but then obviously the ads don't run.

Any ideas what might have changed?

In AndroidManifest:

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="ca-app-pub-2882944708681916~4204025586" />
```

In build.gradle:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.8.0'
implementation "com.android.billingclient:billing:3.0.3"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have the same problem today. a lot of users contacted me saying that my app is crashing on start.
I checked my play console crashes and it have huge number of crashes and lot of users impacted with this issue
The only stack trace is this
/data/app/com.android.chrome-p65-sPd3ac7AycjqzKIQbg==/base.apk

I did not update my app it just happed by it self
I found this
https://groups.google.com/g/google-admob-ads-sdk/c/Q-edauZ27g8
It happed before and still

Not all devices affected by this issue. My app in my phone is working fine. However I have another phone and I open my app then it crash at start. yesterday it wasn't.

**I updated google chrome then the problem goes away. make sure it's last update of google chrome 22 Mar 2021**

I don't think there is something we can do and I don't know how to announce to my users to update google chrome.

Comment: Thanks, would never have thought to do that. Hope you dont lose too many users because google screwed something up.

Comment: @Not_Bluffing You're welcome. I got a lot of 1 star reviews.

Answer (score 1):

Tell your users to update Android System Webview or Chrome...

Check this article posted on support.google.com,

> On March 22, we began to receive reports that several Google apps,
> including Gmail and Chrome, and partner apps began to crash
> unexpectedly on Android. After conducting an investigation, we
> identified that the issue was related to a recent update to the
> WebView system app.  We halted the update and have posted a new
> version of WebView (89.0.4389.105).  If your device was impacted, the
> steps below will walk you through your options to resolve this issue.
>
> To resolve this issue,  Android System WebView and Google Chrome need
> to be updated. Google Play will soon download the update to these apps
> on affected devices, or you can update manually to resolve the issue
> immediately. Some devices do not have WebView pre-installed and only
> need to update Chrome. To manually update Android System WebView and
> Google Chrome right now:
>
> - Open the Play Store app.
> - Search for “Android System WebView.”
> - Select Update. If it doesn't say “Update”, skip this step.
> - Repeat these steps for Google Chrome Learn more about updating Android apps
>
> Note: We do not recommend manually uninstalling updates to WebView. It
> may result in loss of data from some apps.
>
> In some rare cases in Android 10 or 11, a manual update of WebView or
> Chrome may fail to complete. Here are additional steps users can take
> to resolve the issue:
>
> - Open your phone’s Settings app.
> - Tap Apps & notifications > Google Play Store > Storage & cache > Clear Data
>
> Please note that doing this will clear some of your Play Store
> settings like parental controls, auto-update preferences, etc.  Please
> recheck these settings after following these steps. Repeat the steps
> above to update WebView and Chrome

Reference,

https://support.google.com/android/thread/103561027?hl=en